# Android WebView : how do I control webView height?

Tags: android, html, css, webview, android-webview

I am developping an android apps and I want to comunicate with the users giving them some informations as admob ads. 
I want to use "WebView" and to fix its height to "50dp". How do i fix the height from the server (html fille or css) to fit exactly the "50dp" on the client (no verticall scrolling).
Thank you

Comment: Try this `webView.clearView();
  webView.measure(50, 50);` **Is not working on all of devices**

Comment: many thks!!! It is ok now§ I set the Height of my WebView to wrap_content and fix the height from the server. thank you!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a dynamic height in your WebView, you can set the width of your WebView to wrap_content (this is the **device** part).
Then load a proper html which has a fixed height (this is the **server** part).